# Como atualizar ou escolher uma versão específica do phpMyAdmin quando se usa docker-compose.yml?

Tags: phpmyadmin, docker

Usando o arquivo *docker-compose.yml* para montar meus *containers*, sei que posso escolher qualquer versão para o serviço escolhido, por exemplo: *mariadb:latest* ou mariadb:10.4. Mas usando as configurações para o phpMyAdmin, se existir o *container* na minha máquina, de um projeto antigo, como eu posso atualiza-lo e no caso se for montar um novo, como puxar uma versão especifica?
Não achei nada no docker hub em relação à isso.

```
 version: "3"
    services:
      db:
       image: mariadb:latest
       ports:
       - "3306:3306"

      pma:
       image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
       environment:
        PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
        PMA_HOST: db
        PMA_USER: dev
        PMA_PASSWORD: dev123
        PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
        PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
       restart: always
       ports:
       - "8001:80"
       volumes:
       - ./src/sessions:/sessions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toda imagem é definida por [owner]/[repositório]:[tag], as imagens da library (imagens oficiais) não possuem owner.

Quando suprimimos a tag, automaticamente dizemos para o docker que devemos pegar a "latest". Portanto você precisa ir no docker hub, achar a imagem adequada e olhar suas tags. Encontrará as tags disponíveis assim.

Depois é só acertar teu docker-compose, colocando a tag que corresponda à versão que deseja.

O único ponto de atenção, é que não necessariamente a versão que você quer pode estar disponível no docker hub. Isso acontece.

Comment: O engraçado é que é uma imagem oficial e possui owner (https://hub.docker.com/r/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/). Eu havia feito a pergunta, pois não puxava versão antiga.

Comment: Mas exatamente o que você falou, "não necessariamente a versão que você quer pode estar disponível ".

Comment: Imagem oficial, são imagens publicadas pela docker. Esse repositório é do vendor. Isso não é considerado imagem oficial (é meio que uma convenção). A imagens oficiais estão aqui https://hub.docker.com/search?q=&type=image&image_filter=official

Answer (score 0):

Para o **phpMyAdmin**, a imagem mais antiga possível de ser utilizada usando docker para montar container é a de **versão 4.6**. Então para nível de teste ou seja lá qual for a intenção, uma imagem de versão anterior não é possível ser montada.

**Exemplo de erro ao tentar montar utilizado a tag menor que 4.6:**

```
code@Inspiron:~/www/phpmyadmin$ docker-compose up
Pulling pma (phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.5)...
ERROR: manifest for phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.5 not found

code@Inspiron:~/www/phpmyadmin$ docker-compose up
Pulling pma (phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.0.0)...
ERROR: manifest for phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.0.0 not found

code@Inspiron:~/www/phpmyadmin$ docker-compose up
Pulling pma (phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:3.5.8.2)...
ERROR: manifest for phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:3.5.8.2 not found
```

Só a partir da **versão 4.6**

```
version: "3"
    services:
      pma:
       image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.6
       environment:
        PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
        PMA_HOST: meuhostaqui
        PMA_USER: dev
        PMA_PASSWORD: dev123
        PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE: 1G
        PHP_MAX_INPUT_VARS: 1G
       restart: always
       ports:
       - "8001:80"
       volumes:
       - ./src/sessions:/sessions
```

Daí a coisa funciona:

```
code@Inspiron:~/www/phpmyadmin$ docker-compose up
Pulling pma (phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.6)...
4.6: Pulling from phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
627beaf3eaaf: Pulling fs layer
...
```